# looping through website directory

Tags: php, loops, iteration

I need to loop through [this URL](http://anambaskab.go.id/isolinux/Cisco.IOS.Big%20Collection/) and copy every file in any mean, there is no specific way in my mind. I don't have access to the FTP .. Only access is through the URL provided.

Is this possible to be done??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use wget and have it [download recursively](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html) all links up to a certain depth.

Comment: is there another way? I was thinking if there is a way in PHP.

Comment: thats the easiest way. 
you could programm your own recursice functions though, but that would need actual programming skills.

Comment: I do have programming skills :) .. But for this, I don't know where to start :( .. Ok, I consider your update to be the best as you are pointing me to the direction of creating my own recursive function .. I've done it before, but forgot it .. I'll see about that

Comment: you have to get the contents of your url, parse it somehow (dom-parser, regex, ...), find new urls and get their contents. basically you would reinvent the wheel and write your own wget.